# Unusual NullReferenceException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I am getting an unusual null reference when I run this code.

Just to clear up, i understand what a null reference is, none of the values that are used in this method are null when it runs. The null reference appears to be somewhere in mscorlib, i have been unable to find anyone reporting a similar issue so far.

Feature is a enum with with 10 or so items in it.

```
private Dictionary<Feature, bool> dict = new Dictionary<Feature, bool>();

public bool AddFeature(Feature val)
{
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(val))
        {
            dict.Add(val, false);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
}
```

Feature

```
[Flags]
public enum Feature
{
    [Description("Other")]
    Other = 0x00000000,

    [Description("Analysis")]
    Analysis = 0x00000001,

    [Description("Campaign")]
    Campaign = 0x00000002,

    [Description("Trends")]
    Trends = 0x00000004,

    [Description("Portal")]
    Portal = 0x00000008,

    [Description("Phone")]
    Phone = 0x00000010,

    [Description("Rents")]
    Rents = 0x00000020,

    [Description("Repairs")]
    Repairs = 0x00000040,

    [Description("Maintenance")]
    Maintenance = 0x00000080,

    [Description("Management")]
    Management = 0x00000100,

    [Description("Services")]
    Services = 0x00000200,

    [Description("All")]
    All = 0x7FFFFFFF
}
```

The error is:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    at Test.Model.EnabledFeatures.AddFeature(Feature val) in C:\Sandbox\Test\Shared\Model\EnabledFeatures.cs:line 26
```

I have stepped through my code and the error occurs on the

```
dict.Add(val, false);
```

line. When I break at that point, neither `dict` nor `val` is null and both have their expected value.

This code used to work, then I was away from it for a few weeks and came back to find it failing. I am wondering if some Windows or Visual Studio updates could have broken this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: a) It looks like you want a HashSet. b) val is null OR a value of val is null and you have a custom comparer that is trying to use that null value.

Comment: @john: That is not the case. OP doesn't look like he is unknown to this exception. All he cannot contemplate is where this is happening from.

Comment: @CJM: Any other thread that null it?

Comment: Is the "feature" class yours? If so, is there any method that could be used by the Dictionnary class when the `val` is being added? Something like GetHashCode ? Compare? Something else?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal To be honest, the "What is a null...?" post is still 100% valid here. Something about the Feature class it null or returning null. Presumably the Equals and GetHashCode() methods have been overriden and are relying on a value which is null.

Comment: Updated the post for claity. Feature class is an enum with afew values, the method is passed a valid enum.

Comment: Wrap your method in a `try-catch` and dig into the `Exception`, post the Stack Trace here and any further information you can find.

Comment: Added the stack trace to the question.

Comment: @CJM Do you have multiple threads that access `dict`?

Comment: Please show code of your **Feature** class

Comment: Added Feature Code.

Comment: No there is not multiple threads accessing dict.

Comment: @CJM Can you try and create a [MCVE] for this? Are there any particular circumstances this happens in? Try and reproduce the problem again...

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure what the issue was but i have fixed it now by reinstalling .net and many of my visual studio components and packages.